# Is there a way of improving performance when querying views?

Tags: sql, performance, reporting-services, view

I only have access to views for querying data and do not have the permissions to use stored procedures.  So to try an get round these issues I've used temporary tables in my query and added an index to the one calling data from a very big table.  The performance is still shocking and Report Builder times out after 10 minutes of it running.

Does anyone have any other suggestion on how I can improve the performance with the limited resources available?

This is the temporary table for the View that's causing issues:

```
    CREATE TABLE #RPM04STAGEHIST (
    [JOB-NO] VARCHAR(24)
    ,[STAGE-MAP] VARCHAR(6)
    ,[STAGE-DATE] DATETIME
    ,INDEX [JOB-STAGE] ([JOB-NO],[STAGE-MAP])
    );

    INSERT INTO #RPM04STAGEHIST
    SELECT [JOB-NO],[STAGE-MAP],[STAGE-DATE]
    FROM [RM-STAGE-HISTORY]
    WHERE [ORG-CODE] = N'01' 
    AND [JOB-NO] IN (SELECT [JOB-NO] FROM [RM-JOB] WHERE [RM-JOB].[DATE- 
    COMP] >= @DATECOMP AND [RM-JOB].[DATE-COMP] <= @DATECOMP2) 
    AND [STAGE-CODE] IN 
    (N'110',N'117',N'407',N'408',N'409',N'410',N'415',N'418',N'420',N'421');
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us with code so we can see what you have already and see if we can improve on things?

Comment: Have added the temporary table that's causing the issues.  I'm using the results from this temporary table to update the first temporary table.  Thanks.

Comment: try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of your query. if that speeds things up then it's most likely parameter sniffing that's causing the issue, your query may be using a bad query plan. `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` will ignore stored query plans.

Comment: Might speed things up to change that IN subquery to a JOIN on `JOB-NO`. Are your parameters and `DATE-COMP` Dates - converting a string to a date also takes a little time.